# loadLayout() how can I find the according template?

Tags: layout, magento-1, controllers, render

If I do see this function in my controller - **how does Magento knows which layout (and templates) it needs to load/show?**

```
public function upsellAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Finding the layout of your module

In your module `etc/config.xml` you can find the following:

```
<layout>
    <updates>
        <module module="Vendor_Module">
            <file>path/to.xml</file>
        </module>
    </updates>
</layout>
```

If this node is located under the `<frontend>` node you'll will that file under `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/path/to.xml`. In case this node is under the `<adminhtml>` node it will be under `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/path/to.xml`

### Finding the right handle for this action method

First, you need to find out the route name of your module.

It's located under your module folder in the `etc/config.xml`

If you're dealing with a frontend controller it would be under the `<frontend>` node:

```
    <routers>
        <customfrontname>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Vendor_Module</module>
                <frontName>customfrontname</frontName>
            </args>
        </customfrontname>
    </routers>
```

In the example above, your frontname is `customfrontname`.

In case of a backend controller the frontend will always be `adminhtml` if your store is patched.

Now, you need to find your controller name, it's not hard it's the start of your controller file.

Example if your controller is called `CustomController.php` it will be `custom`.

Finally, the last part is the start of your method name.

In your case as your method is called `upsellAction` it will be `upsell`.

To summarize, in my example, your layout handle will be `<customfrontname_custom_upsell>` in case of a frontend controller and `<adminhtml_custom_upsell>` in case of a backend controller.

Now, you just need to open the layout file found in the first part and look what's inside those layout handles nodes.